# Finding strings between two sub string in a text using Regex or any string manipulation

Tags: python, regex

I have a string, `txt` as follows:

```
page_break <abc@email.com> Tue, Jul 30, 2019 at 1:40 AM To: <xyz@email.com>, 
Hello xyz, 
please see attached the document we were looking for
abrcadabra
page_break
To:
```

What I am looking for to extract text from `<abc@email.com>` to 2nd occurrence of `To:`

So the output looks like:

```
Hello xyz, 
please see attached the document we were looking for
abrcadabra
```

While I have tried `regex` like `re.findall(r'<abc@email.com>(.*?)To:', txt,re.DOTALL)` this is not giving the correct result.Instead it is throwing the following

```
[('', ''),....#similar like this]
```

Can anybody help on this? Besides, if I want to make the start string i.e. `<abc@email.com>` as a dynamic one i.e. read from `['<abc@email.com>','<mnop@email.com>']` how to handle the same? 
P.S: I am equally good to see anything without regex as well.

Comment: Without re.DOTALL, try `<abc@email\.com>.*?To:.*((\r?\n(?!To:).*)*)` https://regex101.com/r/IxHYVl/1

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Then try `<(?:abc|mnop)@email\.com>.*?To:.*((\r?\n(?!To:).*)*)`   https://regex101.com/r/tpTowj/1 or use `\w+` instead of `(?:abc|mnop)`

Comment: Neither of your regex are working in scenarios

Comment: What are the scenarios where it does not work? Are they different from the example data?

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `re.findall` with the following regex pattern:

```
\bTo: <[^>]+@[^>]+>,\s*(.*?)\bTo:
```

When used in DOT ALL mode, this will capture all content after the email appearing before the content, up to, but not including, the `To:` label at the end.

Sample script:

```
inp = """page_break <abc@email.com> Tue, Jul 30, 2019 at 1:40 AM To <xyz@email.com>,
Hello xyz, 
please see attached the document we were looking for
abrcadabra
page_break
To:"""

matches = re.findall(r'\bTo: <[^>]+@[^>]+>,\s*(.*?)\bTo:', inp, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(matches)

['Hello xyz, \nplease see attached the document we were looking for\nabrcadabra\npage_break\n']
```

Comment: This is a good approach, however, we need to ensure that this mail body belongs to the sender `abc@email.com` or `mnop@email.com`. I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This regex:

```
r'(?:<(?:abc|mnop)@email.com>.*?\n)(.*?)(?:\f\nTo:)'
```

will accept either `<abc@email.com>` or `<mnop@email.com>`. The actual code below uses a different regex that will only recognize one email at a time, which is a variable.

1. `(?:<(?abc|mnop)@email.com>.*?\n)` Matches `<abc@email.com>` or `<mnop@email.com>` through the end of the line in a non-capturing group.
2. `(.*?)` Matches everything up to the next pattern (i.e., 3.) in a capturing group.
3. `(?:\f\nTo:)` Matches `\f\nTo:` in a non-capturing group.

The code:

```
import re

text = """\f <abc@email.com> Tue, Jul 30, 2019 at 1:40 AM To: <xyz@email.com>,
Hello xyz,
please see attached the document we were looking for
abrcadabra
\f
To:

Some more:

\f <mnop@email.com> Tue, Jul 30, 2019 at 1:40 AM To: <xyz@email.com>,
Hello you all,
Thanks for your quick reply.
\f
To:
"""

emails = ['abc@email.com', 'mnop@email.com']
for email in emails:
    print(email, '->', re.findall(rf'(?:<{email}>.*?\n)(.*?)(?:\f\nTo:)', text, flags=re.DOTALL))
```

Prints:

```
abc@email.com -> ['Hello xyz,\nplease see attached the document we were looking for\nabrcadabra\n']
mnop@email.com -> ['Hello you all,\nThanks for your quick reply.\n']
```

Comment: where is this `\f` is coming from ?

Comment: @pythondumb That was my best guess as to what a "pagebreak" was, i.e. a form-feed.

Comment: Lets assume that the email IDs are in list as given in the question. How can we pass the list element in regex?

Comment: @pythondumb I have updated the code to successively try email addresses taken from list elements. I am not sure if that is is exactly what you are looking for. If you can be more precise ...